# Sign the click one manifest is disabled

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I need to create the test certificate but for some reason tab "Signing" becomes disabled in my project.
[image]

I have no "Security tab" in my project where I can enable it.

Comment: ClickOnce deployment is not an option for your project type, no major mystery and has nothing to do with "create the test certificate".  Whatever that might mean.  Code signing requires running the SignTool.exe utility.

Comment: It was available for my project for a long time and when I just re-open project it becomes unavailable.

Comment: "create the test certificate" is an option that allows one to have a certificate that may be used temporarily.

Comment: @HansPassant - do you happen to know which project types are amenable to ClickOnce deployment and which aren't?  I can't find this information anywhere!